# Detect if FaultException is from remote source

Tags: .net, wcf, faultexception

I have a distributed server application.

A client connects to a slave server and calls a method which is propagated to the master server. The master server throws a `FaultException<CustomFault>()`.

The slave server propagates that `FaultException<CustomFault>()` to the connected client then. But the client receives the non-generic `FaultException` instead.

If I catch and rethrow it (create a new instance of `FaultException<CustomFault>`) on slave server it works as expected:

```
    protected void Rethrow(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (FaultException<CustomFault> kEx)
        {
            throw new FaultException<CustomFault>(kEx.Detail);
        }
    }
```

Therefore I assume that all my interfaces are decorated correctly. I can only assume that microsoft considers throwing FaultExceptions via several servers is considered a security issue...

How can I identify that the FaultException was thrown from a different server? Checking the call stack for:

```
Server stack trace: 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

seems wrong to me. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else has the same problem:

If the `FaultException` is from a remote source - the `Action` property inidicates the service!